# Need help with USB passthrough on QEMU

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have created a windows VM using virt-manager QEMU/KVM.
Its works perfectly and I am able to use it.
I have a second set of a keyboard and a mouse that I want to connect only to the virtual machine.
I tried to do this by clicking add hardware, USB host device, select the keyboard and click finish. When I try and boot the VM this is the error I get.

What should I do?

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2017-06-29T17:04:26.213999Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=4,id=hostdev0,bus=usb.0,port=2: failed to find host usb device 1:4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 90, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 126, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 83, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1035, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2017-06-29T17:04:26.213999Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=4,id=hostdev0,bus=usb.0,port=2: failed to find host usb device 1:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to pass through a USB device that does not exist:

```
failed to find host usb device 1:4
```

There is no USB device on bus 1 address 4.

Most likely the problem is that the device is at a different address.

Try using the `lsusb` command to locate the correct address for the device, and then editing the libvirt XML configuration for the VM to provide the correct address.